# Toggle state of object key value in an array

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I need to create a reducer that toggles the state of done using the id or index of the todo

```js
state = {
    todos: [
      {
        title: "eat rice",
        done: false,
        id: 1
      },
      {
        title: "go fishing",
        done: true,
        id: 2
      },
      {
        title: "drink coffee",
        done: false,
        id: 3
      }
    ]
  }
```

I tried  this but it mutates the state, the payload being the index of the object in the array.

```js
case "DONE":
      const todos = [...state.todos];
      todos[action.payload].done = !todos[action.payload].done;
      return {
        ...state,
        todos: todos
      };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function instead. The function will generate a new array which you can use to replaces `todos` with.

```js
case "DONE":
  const newTodos = state.todos.map((todo, index) => {
    // Based on your code, I assume action.payload is the index of the todo in the array of todos
    if (index === action.payload) {
      const newTodo = {...todo};
      todo.done = !todo.done;
      return todo;
    }

    return todo;
  });

  return {
    ...state,
    todos: newTodos,
  };
```

If you don't want to iterate over every `todo`, you could do something else such as using [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to create a copy of the array and then change the one value:

```js
case "DONE":
  const newTodos = todos.slice();
  const updatedTodo = {...newTodos[action.payload]};
  updatedTodo.done = !updatedTodo.done;
  newTodos[action.payload] = updatedTodo;

  return {
    ...state,
    todos: newTodos,
  };
```

Comment: This example line is still mutating: `newTodos[action.paylod].done = !newTodos[action.paylod].done;`.  See the [Redux docs page on "Immutable Update Patterns"](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/immutableupdatepatterns) for an explanation, as well as Dave Ceddia's post [The Complete Guide to Immutability in React and Redux](https://daveceddia.com/react-redux-immutability-guide/).

Comment: Using redux-logger, it shows that both methods mutate the state. Any other way around it?

Comment: Hmm. I guess you got it working, but I understand the issue from the docs @markerikson linked. The solution would be to create a new object for the one being replaced: `const newTodo = { ...todos[action.payload] }; newTodo[action.payload].done = !newTodo[action.payload].done`; That should create a new copy of both the array and the individual object within it.

Comment: The code snippet in this answer is still incorrect.  `const newTodo = todo;  todo.done = !todo.done;` is making one of the mistakes referenced in the docs page - it's simply another variable pointing to the same object in memory, and still mutating it.  I'll edit the answer to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using the spread operator or map will create a new array but will not automatically clone the contained objects, as JavaScript follows "pass by reference". You'd have to clone the object as well. So maybe something like

```
case "DONE":
  const todos = state.todos.map((todo, index) => {
    const newTodo = {...todo};
    if (action.payload === index) {
      newTodo.done = !todo.done;
    }
    return newTodo;
  });

  return {
    ...state,
    todos,
  };
```

Of course you could also use a clone utility or something like Immutable.js.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Thanks for the contributions.

```
case "DONE":
      const newTodos = state.todos.map((todo, index) => {
        if (index === action.payload) {
          const newTodo = { ...todo };
          newTodo.done = !newTodo.done;
          return newTodo;
        }

        return todo;
      });

      return {
        ...state,
        todos: newTodos
      };
```

Comment: Hah cool, we came up with pretty much the same thing. See my answer for why https://stackoverflow.com/a/52600197/271442